# jenkins deploy with hibernate create-drop option

Tags: java, hibernate, jenkins

To enforce the create-drop hibernate option I need to shutdown tomcat(?), however if I were to do that my jenkins server is also shut down. At the moment the jenins job simply builds the war and then copies it to webapps directory.

I want to enforce the create drop hibernate option on my web app without restarting tomcat/jenkins, is their a way to do this ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to restart the container (Tomcat) but the web app for this to be triggered, which should happen by undeploying/deploying/starting the web app. Your Tomcat seems to be configured to do this automatically (copying a .war into the webapps directory) so it _should_ happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other users already stated you do not have to restart tomcat in order the restart a web application inside it. There is a deploy plugin available in Jenkins which is perfect for your scenario: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin .

By the way, Jenkins comes with an embedded Jetty server so it is very straightforward to run this outside tomcat:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins

In case you are just starting with this application then consider using Liquibase to manage your DB creation, upgrades, ...: http://www.liquibase.org/ . It can be integrated with hibernate if desired and you could then easily create a Jenkins jobs that does a liquibase drop_all/update to recreate your database (schema) without touching your running application.

Comment: and that redeploy will enforce the dropping of database as specified by hibernate ? I am copying the war file across at the moment(using jenkins command line), which forces a redeploy doesn't it ?

Comment: yes, it will restart your application and thereby reload your context.

Answer (score 1):

Well i think you don't **have** to restart the server just redeploy the application.

Comment: How can I do this as part of my jenkins job, is their a command I can run (jenkins job has command line option)

Comment: Maybe this can help:
http://morethanseven.net/2011/03/20/A-continuous-deployment-example-setup.html
Or this:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin